# Append function in body tag of all pages in website

Tags: c#, html, .net

We are having a web project which is having around 100 front-end pages. I needed to create a new functionality that invoke certain method on browser/tab close (Used onbeforeunload).

**Question is:**
Now, I need to add these two new methods (onmousedown=f1(); and onbforeunload=f2();) on every front-end page. I thought of making use of PageBase from which all the pages are inheriting. But, I am not able to get BODY tag in PageBase class. I tried:

```
 private void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("bodyId");
        body.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "Mouseclick()");
        //body.Attributes.Add("onunload", "Function2()");
    }
```

But body is always null here. Please help me on this.
Thanks...

Comment: I used Javascript to resolve it. Added an immediate function to call a function once document is loaded. Then in that function, I am binding the required events to body...

Answer (score 0):

you can define PageBase, and override Render method， following：

```
    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("key", "scripturl");
    base.Render(writer);
```

define your method onmousedown, onbforeunload in scripturl , good luck